# How to know if global module is invoked or local?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, node-modules

A node-module can be installed at local level or at global level by adding `-g` while doing `npm install`.

If a module (for example `mocha`) is installed both locally and globally, which one will be loaded when I do  `require( "mocha" );`?

And how can I know which one of them is being used loaded in the execution environment of node now?

Comment: I think the application search first in local when project will be run, and if find it, will be use it. I think this way because of package.json, as allow to put some configuration in dependencies and libs.

Comment: I think you cannot check with in you code but in your package.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node will search for local modules first and if it doesn't find the right module there - it will proceed searching in other places as can be seen here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

You should be able to use `require.resolve('mocha')` to determine the location of the currently loaded module. That way you can tell which one is loaded. If it sits under your project directory - it's local - otherwise it's global.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can use:

```
$ export NODE_DEBUG=module
```

And then run your command.  This will give you a detailed log of all the modules that you are loading and where they are coming from.

If you want it just for a single command, you can run:

```
$ NODE_DEBUG=module <command>
```

The only warning is that this displays *a lot* of information.  So `grep` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.